# How to rotate a finger 90/180/270 drgress around the origin point in screen coordinates in javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a point (1,0) in screen coordinates  then rotate 90/180/270 drgress clockwise around the origin point(1,2)  across the rotate I get a new point (3,2) So I want to use javascript function to achieve it
like

function rotatePoint(x,y,originX,originY,angle){
....
}

How to use javascript to achieve this function?
[image]

Comment: need more details , not able to understand the issue

Comment: Please visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research - [search SO for answers](https://www.google.com/search?q=javascript+rotate+point+site%3Astackoverflow.com).  If you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the [\[<>\]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) snippet editor.

Answer (score 1):

You will need one more field that is angle. Only if you want to make it dynamic.

```
function rotatePoint(x, y, originX, originY, angle) {
    // Convert angle to radians
    var radians = (angle * Math.PI) / 180;

    // Calculate the new coordinates
    var newX = Math.cos(radians) * (x - originX) - Math.sin(radians) * (y - originY) + originX;
    var newY = Math.sin(radians) * (x - originX) + Math.cos(radians) * (y - originY) + originY;

    return { x: newX, y: newY };
}

// Example
var originalPoint = { x: 1, y: 0 };
var originPoint = { x: 1, y: 2 };

var rotatedPoint = rotatePoint(originalPoint.x, originalPoint.y, originPoint.x, originPoint.y, 90);

console.log(rotatedPoint);
```

Do let me know if this is what you were looking for. And also this is dynamic because itis taking angle values dynamically instead of using it in function.

Comment: Strange!!!
I asked ChatGPT and got the same answer as you posted :)))

Comment: Yes because this is a mathematical calculation and even I took the help of tool. But I made sure in my local system that it works and fits the requirement. Not just copy pastting the code from chat gpt. Thank you.

Comment: you can use it for your own purpose.Please, Check the new policy from StackOverflow https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/421831/temporary-policy-generative-ai-e-g-chatgpt-is-banned

Comment: Oh, I was unaware about this. Thank you for this. I will take care of it from next time. Thanks for this :)